# Appium Inspector not able to load image

Tags: appium

Details : Appium 1.4.13 ; Mac OSX

While this feature was working fine until some time back before the 1.4.13 was released but ever since then I am unable to refresh the view of the Appium Inspector for my application. The hierarchy is loaded but the IMAGE is not displayed. Even on clicking Refresh the following logs are generated :

> 2015-11-20 06:16:33:244 - info: --> GET
>   /wd/hub/session/95abc888-6917-45c7-b004-155de500244e/source {}
>
> 2015-11-20 06:16:33:244 - info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work
>   queue: ["source",{}]
>
> 2015-11-20 06:16:33:248 - info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data
>   from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"source","params":{}} 2015-11-20
>   06:16:33:248 - info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type
>   ACTION 2015-11-20 06:16:33:248 - info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got
>   command action: source
>
> 2015-11-20 06:16:33:259 - info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT]
>   [APPIUM-UIAUTO] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":" esc=\"\" checkable=\"false\"
>   checked=\"false\" clickable=\"false\" enabled=\ 2015-11-20
>   06:16:33:260 - info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] "true\"
>   focusable=\"false\" focused=\"false\" scrollable=\"false\"
>   long-clickable=\"false\" password=\"false\" selected=\"false\"
>   bounds=\"[15,169][753,188]\" resource-id=\"\"
>   instance=\"0\"/></android.widget.RelativeLayout></android.widget.LinearLayout>
>   content-desc=\"\" checkable=\"false\" checked=\"false\"
>   clickable=\"true\" enabled=\"true\" focusable=\"false\"
>   focused=\"false\" scrollable=\"false\" long-c 2015-11-20 06:16:33:262
>   - info: [debug] Stream still not complete, waiting 2015-11-20 06:16:33:262 - info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] lickable=\"false\"
>   password=\"false\" selected=\"false\" bounds=\"[15,326][753,366]\"
>   resource-id=\"com.flipkart.android:id/btn_mlogin\"
>   instance=\"3\"/></android.widget.LinearLayout></android.widget.ScrollView></android.widget.RelativeLayout></android.widget.LinearLayout></android.widget.ViewSwitcher></android.widget.FrameLayout></android.widget.LinearLayout></android.widget.FrameLayout></hierarchy>"}[/APPIUM-UIAUTO]
>   2015-11-20 06:16:33:265 - info: [debug] Stream still not complete,
>   waiting 2015-11-20 06:16:33:266 - info: [debug] Responding to client
>   with success: {"status":0,"value":" 2015-11-20 06:16:33:267 - info: <-- GET
>   /wd/hub/session/95abc888-6917-45c7-b004-155de500244e/source 200 23.308
>   ms - 9023 {"status":0,"value":" 2015-11-20 06:16:33:269 - info: -->
>   GET /wd/hub/session/95abc888-6917-45c7-b004-155de500244e/orientation
>   {} 2015-11-20 06:16:33:270 - info: [debug] Pushing command to appium
>   work queue: ["orientation",{}] 2015-11-20 06:16:33:273 - info: [debug]
>   [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client:
>   {"cmd":"action","action":"orientation","params":{}} 2015-11-20
>   06:16:33:273 - info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type
>   ACTION 2015-11-20 06:16:33:274 - info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got
>   command action: orientation 2015-11-20 06:16:33:274 - info: [debug]
>   [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Current rotation: ROTATION_0 2015-11-20
>   06:16:33:274 - info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result:
>   {"status":0,"value":"PORTRAIT"} 2015-11-20 06:16:33:274 - info:
>   [debug] Responding to client with success:
>   {"status":0,"value":"PORTRAIT","sessionId":"95abc888-6917-45c7-b004-155de500244e"}
>   2015-11-20 06:16:33:275 - info: <-- GET
>   /wd/hub/session/95abc888-6917-45c7-b004-155de500244e/orientation 200
>   5.853 ms - 82 {"status":0,"value":"PORTRAIT","sessionId":"95abc888-6917-45c7-b004-155de500244e"}
>   2015-11-20 06:16:33:277 - info: --> GET
>   /wd/hub/session/95abc888-6917-45c7-b004-155de500244e/screenshot {}
>   2015-11-20 06:16:33:278 - info: [debug] executing cmd:
>   /Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s
>   192.168.56.101:5555 shell "/system/bin/rm /data/local/tmp/screenshot.png; /system/bin/screencap -p
>   /data/local/tmp/screenshot.png "
>
> 2015-11-20 06:16:33:354 - info: [debug] executing cmd:
>   /Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s
>   192.168.56.101:5555 pull /data/local/tmp/screenshot.png "/var/folders/9_/zhwc774n3kx8k1g7s_n3q9n15by3jh/T/appium1151020-1782-57al17.png"
>
> 2015-11-20 06:16:33:394 - info: [debug] Responding to client with
>   success:
>   {"status":0,"value":"","sessionId":"95abc888-6917-45c7-b004-155de500244e"}
>
> 2015-11-20 06:16:33:395 - info: <-- GET
>   /wd/hub/session/95abc888-6917-45c7-b004-155de500244e/screenshot 200
>   118.561 ms - 74 {"status":0,"value":"","sessionId":"95abc888-6917-45c7-b004-155de500244e"}
>
> 2015-11-20 06:16:33:398 - info: --> GET
>   /wd/hub/session/95abc888-6917-45c7-b004-155de500244e/contexts {}
>   2015-11-20 06:16:33:398 - info: [debug] Getting a list of available
>   webviews 2015-11-20 06:16:33:398 - info: [debug] executing cmd:
>   /Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s
>   192.168.56.101:5555 shell "cat /proc/net/unix"
>
> 2015-11-20 06:16:33:442 - info: [debug] WEBVIEW_3598 mapped to pid
>   3598
>
> 2015-11-20 06:16:33:442 - info: [debug] Getting process name for
>   webview 2015-11-20 06:16:33:443 - info: [debug] executing cmd:
>   /Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s
>   192.168.56.101:5555 shell "ps"
>
> 2015-11-20 06:16:33:485 - info: [debug] Parsed pid: 3598 pkg:
>   com.flipkart.android
>
> 2015-11-20 06:16:33:486 - info: [debug] from:
>   u0_a67,3598,465,1106360,97644,ffffffff,b7577d05,S,com.flipkart.android
>   2015-11-20 06:16:33:486 - info: [debug] returning process name:
>   com.flipkart.android 2015-11-20 06:16:33:486 - info: [debug] Available
>   contexts: NATIVE_APP,WEBVIEW_com.flipkart.android 2015-11-20
>   06:16:33:486 - info: [debug] ["WEBVIEW_com.flipkart.android"]
>   2015-11-20 06:16:33:486 - info: [debug] Available contexts:
>   NATIVE_APP,WEBVIEW_com.flipkart.android 2015-11-20 06:16:33:487 -
>   info: [debug] Responding to client with success:
>   {"status":0,"value":["NATIVE_APP","WEBVIEW_com.flipkart.android"],"sessionId":"95abc888-6917-45c7-b004-155de500244e"}
>   2015-11-20 06:16:33:488 - info: <-- GET
>   /wd/hub/session/95abc888-6917-45c7-b004-155de500244e/contexts 200
>   90.058 ms - 117 {"status":0,"value":["NATIVE_APP","WEBVIEW_com.flipkart.android"],"sessionId":"95abc888-6917-45c7-b004-155de500244e"}

Comment: upgrade to 1.4.14 and see if that solved the issue.

Comment: update not available as of now to 100% users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the installation of the Appium itself. Tried to `upgrade` the app from 1.4.8 to 1.4.13 instead of installing the app from a `.dmg` for 1.4.13.